# Oracle APEX - Transferring page item value from one page to another

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Not sure what am I doing wrong and need help to diagnose the issue.

I have an apex page with an IG on it with radiobutton selection column, allowing the user to select only one row at a time.

On row select I use javascript to grab the ID of the selected row and then use Execute PL/SQL

```
NULL;
```

in order to store the value into the session state of `P2_ID`.

I also have a button on the page that has another page as a target - page 3, and I need to get my P2_ID value to that page.

So I set the page item of a target page - `P3_ID` ro `&P2_ID.` in a Link Builder - target pop up window. Along with that I pass another page item `P2_TEST`, which has a static value.

Now when I get to page 3, I do not see `P3_I`D in the session state while I do see `P3_TEST` and it does have a value, but `P3_ID` is not even listed... What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: instead of executing `NULL;` when pushing the button, `SUBMIT` (submit will certainly store values into session state). Create a branch which takes you to page 3; among branch properties, you'll find an option to set `P3_ID` to `P2_ID`

Comment: I do not execute NUll when pressing a button, I execute it after the user selects an IG row. That part works fine.   On the button in Behavior property I select "Redirect to a page in this application" and set page number to 3. Then I add an option to set P3_ID to P2_ID. Is that what you mean?

Comment: or do you mean making it a submit page button and create an actual branch process in After Submit?

Comment: A branch would be used if your button SUBMITs the page. If your button redirects and does not submit the page, then yes, add the option in the redirect screen to copy P3_id to P2_id.